# coinbase api call print Null in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

 var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY','apiSecret': 'API SECRET'});

client.getSpotPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

using the code above , console.log gives `null` result?

Comment: And what is error? - `console.log(err, data);`

Comment: getting below error: Error: SSL Error: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot does not support SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Coinbase API peculiarity, you need to tell it not to be too strict, by passing additional parameter `strictSSL` with `false` value:

```js
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
var client = new Client({
                          'apiKey': 'API KEY',
                          'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'
                          'strictSSL': false
                        });

client.getSpotPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I found this trick here:
https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node/issues/77

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pavel

Comment: You can say thanks and help others by accepting and upvoting my answer ;)

Comment: don't you think this is a very high-risk move in terms of security? by not using SSL means the connection is HTTP and not HTTPS (means your secret data (API key and stuff)) all are not encrypted when the protocol is made.

Comment: 100% agree, but Coinbase API gave no choice, at least as of Nov 2017. I hope they fixed their stuff since then.

Comment: best answer.. .'strictSSL': false' did it for me